# Calling a pandas dataframe in a function by giving a stingpath

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want a method to return back a pandas DataFrame by giving it a stringpath as a parameter, which is given by the constructor parameter.

Here is my code:

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self,file):
        self.file = file
        print(self.loadfile(self.file))
        print("------------------------------------")
        print("DESCRIPTION: ", self.loadfile(self.file))


    def loadfile(self,file):
        df = pd.read_csv(self.file)
        return df

        return pd.DataFrame(columns=[file])

    def descript(self,file):

        df = pd.read_csv(self.file)
        return df.descript
```

It is giving me back something but this doens't look like the pandas dataframe you get if you type

df1 = pd.read_csv("blabla.csv")

So where is the error?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you eloborate your thoughts on the `loadfile` function. Why the two return statements ? Can you run add this line within your function `import os; print(os.path.exists(file))`  and show the output

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return a DataFrame as part of `__init__` you will need to call the `loadfile` function after you initialize the class object

```
class TestClass(object):

    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file

    def loadfile(self):
        df = pd.read_csv(self.file)
        return df

TestClass(r'path\to\file.csv').loadfile()
```